# Restore one table only in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup, database-restore

Problem:
I need to restore only one table from a backup. How should I do it in a course of action?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

There are 3rd party tools that can assist in what you are asking for:

[APEX SQL Recover](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-recover-a-single-table-from-a-sql-server-database-backup/)

[Idera SQL Virtual DB](https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver/sqlvirtualdatabase)

They may require registration but offer a fully functional trial to get the job done.